# Using an if loop to create matrix using data from three different dataframes

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, quantile

I have three dataframes. One with means of an original dataset and two that represent the 2.75th percentile and 97.5th percentile of null distributions I created using a loop that sampled the original sample.

I have an if loop created that I want to replicate for each to generate a matrix that looks like the same format as my dataframes but just consisting "-", "+" or "0". These symbols are dependent on if the mean from the first dataframe is greater than the 97.25th percentile variable of the third dataframe, if the mean from the first dataframe is lower than than the 2.75th percentile of the second dataframe, and if the mean from the first dataframe is between these two variables. Any ideas about how to go about doing this if loop to accomplish this?

```
    if (mean > 97.25th percentile){
  print("-")
} else if(mean < 2.75th percentile ) {
  print("+")
} else {
  print("0")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to first initialize an empty `data.frame` before starting the loop.

Then you can use the `if` `else if` `else` structure you were proposing.

```
set.seed(3)
df.mean <- data.frame(mean = runif(100,0,100))
df.2.75 <- data.frame(centil275 = runif(100,1,4))
df.97.5 <- data.frame(centil975 = runif(100,97,100))

df.result <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(df.mean)){
  if(df.mean[i,1] > df.97.5[i,1]) df.result[i,1] <- "-"
  else if(df.mean[i,1] < df.2.75[i,1]) df.result[i,1] <- "+"
  else df.result[i,1] <- "0"
}

df.final <- do.call(cbind,list(df.mean,df.2.75,df.97.5,df.result))
df.final
df.final
#          mean centil275 centil975 V1
#1   16.8041526  3.299013  99.19449  0
#2   80.7516399  3.046397  99.58147  0
#3   38.4942351  1.627392  98.02813  0
#4   32.7734317  3.135831  98.47877  0
#5   60.2100675  2.815895  99.56156  0
#6   60.4394054  2.021678  98.16176  0
#7   12.4633444  1.123511  99.17952  0
#8   29.4600924  2.205258  99.05237  0
#9   57.7609919  1.237179  99.53660  0
#10  63.0979274  1.937658  97.09840  0
#...

table(df.final[,4])
# -  +  0 
# 1  3 96
```

Comment: This is great! But I am receiving this error:Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for ">"Error in FR5_final_means[i, 1] > quantile_high[i, 1] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented

Comment: I suspect that either `FR5_final_means[, 1]` or `quantile_high[, 1]` is of a class other than numeric. You could try `FR5_final_means[, 1] <- as.numeric(as.character(FR5_final_means[, 1]))` and `quantile_high[, 1] <- as.numeric(as.character(quantile_high[, 1]))`. Otherwise, you can provide the output of `str(quantile_high)` and `str(FR5_final_means)` by **editing your original question**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3 dataframe are called `dfm`, `df97` and `df2`, you can use nested `ifelse`.

```
result <- ifelse(dfm > df97, '-', ifelse(dfm < df2, '+', 0))
```

Or using `dplyr::case_when` :

```
result <- dplyr::case_when(df.mean > df.97.5 ~ '-', 
                           df.mean < df.2.75 ~ '+', TRUE~'0')
```